# Run python script in LLDB

Tags: python, lldb

I'd like to debug a Python script that runs some C code under the hood using LLDB. If I simply run `lldb 'python my_script.py'`, LLDB informs me that `error: unable to find executable for 'python my_script.py'`. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

By putting 'python my_script.py' in quotes like that, you are telling lldb that your executable is called 'python my_script.py'.  You want to run the 'python' binary, but supply my_script.py as the first argument.  Do that by saying:

```
$ lldb python my_script.py
```

Note, since the lldb command can take various flag arguments, you can disambiguate flags sent to lldb and flags sent to your program by writing this:

```
$ lldb python -- my_script.py
```

or even more pedantically correct:

```
$ lldb -f python -- my_script.py
```